# Java synchronize data between threads in Executor Service pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to synchronize a int counter between few threads (6). Below is my worker class. I am trying to synchronize my private field `countertest`:

```
public class DbWorker implements Callable {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private int countertest = 0 ;

    private  boolean  IsActive(Integer act)
    {
        synchronized(lock){ 
        boolean exists = false;
        countertest++;
            ....
       System.out.println("countertest  IS :  " + countertest );
         }
       return true;
    }

     public void run() {
        ....
        IsActive(act):
        ...
     }

}
```

In my main class I am creating threads using for loop and ExecutorService. Please see below:

```
private ExecutorCompletionService<Integer> _objQueue ;

 for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
     _objQueue.submit( new DbWorker( "SOME PARAMETER" , _snapshots.get(j) , j )    );
}
```

My countertest variable is not synced it is printing different number (non-sequential). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "duplicate", IMO, is a bad question with a bad answer.  Bad because it promotes the idea that objects can be `static` or not static.  (They can't:  Only _variables_ can be `static` or not static.)  And, bad because it promotes the idea that `static` makes a difference in locking.  (It doesn't.  What matters is, two threads can not lock the same object at the same time.  Whether the `synchronized` statement obtains the reference from a static variable, from a non-static variable, or by calling a method is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

is an instance field. In other words, there's one per `DbWorker` object.

You then submit `DbWorker` instances to for execution

```
_objQueue.submit( new DbWorker( "SOME PARAMETER" , _snapshots.get(j) , j )    );
```

Each thread has its own `DbWorker` and therefore its own lock. Threads are never contending with any other thread.

Create one `DbWorker` and share it among threads, ie. `submit` the same `DbWorker` instance every time.

Comment: I am passing an argument for each DbWorker . I cannot use the same DbWorker.

Comment: @KennerDev Then share the counter and the lock between them. Use an `AtomicInteger` if anything.

Comment: My lock is final already .What else do I need to do ?

Comment: @KennerDev Share it between threads.

Comment: Do u mean using volatile ?

Comment: Oh  mean make the lock Static

Comment: @KennerDev No. Re-read my first paragraph. The lock object (and the counter) are instance variables. You create 6 (`j`) instances. There's nothing shared among them.

Comment: @KennerDev It wouldn't be enough for the lock to be `static`. The counter would have to be as well.

Comment: @KennerDev Assuming you wanted sequential numbers.

Comment: Yes . I am testing it and will let you know in a bit ( slow pc)

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis. Its is working.Thanks much . I missed a very obvious point.Marking it as answer

Answer (score 2):

Because you creating an instance in the loop where where `countertest` and `lock` are instance variable and hence every object will get a new one.

1. `countertest` will always be 1 in this case, it is not shared between instances
2. multiple threads aren't acquiring the same lock, so it is useless.

Comment: I am passing an argument for each DbWorker . I cannot use the same DbWorker.

Comment: I am just answering your question, "why it is not working". I don't know what you trying to do but your code looks so broken anyways